# Efficiently iterate over rows to dynamically/sequentially populate variable going down rows

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to dynamically populate a variable, which requires me to reference rows.

Given are 3 columns: **time**, **group**, and **val**.

I want to populate rows 3, 4, 7, and 8's *val* which are initially ***NA***.

Here is my toy data:

```
df <- expand.grid(time = rep(c(1,2,3,4)), group = rep(c("A", "B")))
df$val <- c(50,40,NA,NA)

df

> df
     time group val
  1    1     A  50
  2    2     A  40
  3    3     A  NA
  4    4     A  NA
  5    1     B  50
  6    2     B  40
  7    3     B  NA
  8    4     B  NA
```

I have two grouping variables (***time*** and ***group***) and, as example, I need to populate ***row 3*** above by this set of rules:

```
1. Order by group and time (in ascending order)
2. For time = 3, the value of **val** is the arithmetic average of two previous rows; 
   (2a). i.e. the average of time 2 and time 1 values, so it will be 1/2 * (40+50) = 45.
3. For time = 4, the value of **val** is the arithmetic average of two previous rows;
    (3a). i.e. the average of time 3 and time 2 values, so it will be 1/2 * (45+40) = 42.5.
```

And so on, going down to the last row of each group as defined by *time* and *group* variables.

I want to avoid using loops and referencing row index to achieve this, and prefer to stay within ***dplyr***, as the rest of my scripts are in the ***dplyr*** ecosystem. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do something like `df$val[is.na(df$val)] <- somevalue`

Comment: In my case, somevalue has to be sequentially populated, so I am unclear how this approach would work?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the cleanest solution, but it gets the job done:

```
df2 = df %>%
    arrange(group, time) %>%
    mutate(val = if_else(is.na(val), (lag(val, n=1) + lag(val, n=2))/2.0, val)) %>%
    mutate(val = if_else(is.na(val), (lag(val, n=1) + lag(val, n=2))/2.0, val))
```

Again, it's not pretty, but it seems to work. Hope that helps give you something to start from.